# Which datatype for running results

Tags: java, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

I want to store running results from both marathons and 100m and then display them in the same table.

persistence is done with jpa2 and frontend with jsf2

So a table would look something like

```
100m   12.52
200m   24.88
10km   42:24.37
Marathon 3:30:31
```

Question: what datatype should be used to persist duration, where jsf might be able to help with the presentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a `TIME` column in DB which is mapped against `java.util.Date` should suffice.

```
@Temporal(TIME)
private Date runningTime;
```

Then you can use standard JSF `<f:convertDateTime>` whereby you ignore the date part by `type="time"` or an appropriate `pattern` (you however still need to take into account that timezone is properly aligned out else you may run into DST issues).